# How can I shift patterns in a string one place ahead (removing the first, replacing the last)?

Tags: python, regex, string, python-re

I have a string in Python, and I would like to shift a pattern 1 place earlier.

This is my string:

```
my_string = [AudioLengthInSecs: 37.4]hello[seconds_silence:
0.65]one[seconds_silence: 0.54]two[seconds_silence: 0.59]three[seconds_silence: 
0.48]hello[seconds_silence: 2.32]
```

I would like to shift the numbers, after **[seconds_silence: XXXX]** one place earlier (and removing the first one, and the last one (since that one is shifted)). The result should be like this:

```
my_desired_string = [AudioLengthInSecs: 37.4]hello[seconds_silence: 0.54]one[seconds_silence: 0.59]two[seconds_silence: 
0.48]three[seconds_silence: 2.32]hello
```

Here is my code:

```
import re

my_string = "[AudioLengthInSecs: 37.4]hello[seconds_silence:0.65]one[seconds_silence: 0.54]two[seconds_silence: 0.59]three[seconds_silence: 0.48]hello[seconds_silence: 2.32]"

# First, find all the numbers in the string 
all_numbers =  (re.findall('\d+', my_string ))

# Secondly, remove the first 4 numbers ()
all_numbers = all_numbers[4:]

# combine the numbers into one string
all_numbers
combined_numbers = [i+j for i,j in zip(all_numbers[::2], all_numbers[1::2])]

# Than loop over the string and instert 


for word in my_string.split(): 
    print(word)
    if word == "[seconds_silence":
        print(word)
        # here i wanted to check if [soconds_silence was recognized
        # and replace with value from combined_numbers
        # however, this is failing obviously
```

Comment: Thanks for replying @WiktorStribiżew. I do understand how I can replace values, however I found this one tricky since it is not just replacing, but shifting. Therefore, I also don't think that this is a duplicate...

Comment: Done, please see post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to find all pairs:

- the string preceding *[seconds_silence: ...]* fragment (capturing group No 1),
- and the above fragment itself (capturing group No 2).

Then:

- drop the first *[seconds_silence: ...]* fragment,
- and join both lists,

but as they now have different length, *itertools.zip_longest* is needed.

So the whole code to do your task is:

```
import itertools
import re

my_string = '[AudioLengthInSecs: 37.4]hello[seconds_silence:0.65]'\
    'one[seconds_silence: 0.54]two[seconds_silence: 0.59]'\
    'three[seconds_silence: 0.48]hello[seconds_silence: 2.32]'
gr1 = []
gr2 = []
for mtch in re.findall(r'(.+?)(\[seconds_silence: ?[\d.]+\])', my_string):
    g1, g2 = mtch
    gr1.append(g1)
    gr2.append(g2)
gr2.pop(0)
my_desired_string = ''
for g1, g2 in itertools.zip_longest(gr1, gr2, fillvalue=''):
    my_desired_string += g1 + g2
print(my_desired_string)
```